Obtaining dead parents social security #
I need to obtain my deceased father's Social Security #. I need it to be able to order a copy of his records from the US Armed Forces.

Have you talked to the Social Security Administration?

Go to your local Social Security office, with as much documentation as you can provide. Photo ID, death certificates, whatever else they need.

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on genealogy.stackexchange.com

@user71659 This is a common requirement for the legal probate process. It isn't the only reason someone needs to know, but it is an important one. It could be appropriate in either forum.

SSNs of deceased people are not private or confidential.
You can obtain the SSN of a deceased person by filling in and submitting FORM SSA-711: REQUEST FOR A DECEASED PERSONS SOCIAL SECURITY NUMBER. There is a fee of $27 which must be submitted at the same time. Go to a Social Security Office or submit the form and payment online.
Social Security Administration does not keep the numbers of deceased persons secret. They will sell full lists. These lists are used by retirement pension funds to verify deaths among their beneficiaries. The death records are obtained from multiple sources. The records are not complete. For example, some people die without having their identity established or no one knows their SSN.
These lists could also be used to purge voter registration records.

A deceased person's SSN is usually listed on his death certificate.

Also on tax records, for example copies of income tax returns, if the deceased kept copies and they are available.
